# How to extract strings from regular expression?

Tags: regex

If you have a regular expression like `test\(\d+,[a-z]+\)`. And it matches with some string, how can you extract the strings which matched `\d+` and `[a-z]+`.

Note: the above was a simple example, the solution should work for any cases.

Answer (score 1):

Add capturing groups:

```
test\((\d+),([a-z]+)\)
```